# Azure Service Fabric outbound IP address

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

In order to access the third party APIs, I have been asked to send the Service Fabric outbound static IP address for whitelisting. Where could I find the outbound IP address in the Portal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your outbound IP address is going to be the Public IP address resource that is associated with your load balancer.

Comment: I'm not finding that to be the case